# Atime don't change on mounted drive

Tags: linux, centos, mount, cat, stat

i have CentOS Stream 9.
when i mount a usb drive and create a file using touch command the Access time in stat command don't change and stays:
"Access: 2023-06-20 03:00:00.000000000 +0300"
it stays like this also when i use the command "cat file"

i try to mount with the following command:
mount -o strictatime,fmask=000 /dev/sdb1 /home/linux1/USB

this is the output of the mount command:

```
[root@localhost USB]# mount | grep "USB"
/dev/sdb1 on /home/linux1/USB type vfat (rw,fmask=0000,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

this is the output of stat command:

```
[root@localhost USB]# stat file
  File: file
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 811h/2065d      Inode: 180         Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:dosfs_t:s0
Access: 2023-06-20 03:00:00.000000000 +0300
Modify: 2023-06-20 23:36:02.000000000 +0300
Change: 2023-06-20 23:36:02.140000000 +0300
 Birth: -
```

there is something more that i have to change to make it work, i dont know what. someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a FAT32 filesystem? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system), date resolution in FAT32 is 1 day for access date.

Your `2023-06-20 03:00:00.000000000 +0300` is midnight in UTC, but [it seems FAT32 does not store any timezone information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38549583/10765659). So this is really just sole `2023-06-20` date with no timezone specified, *interpreted* as midnight in UTC, then translated to your timezone which apparently is `+0300`, hence these `03:00:00` and `+0300` in the output of `stat`. The filesystem itself holds the date only.

To make it work as you expect, you need to use another type of filesystem. If it has to be a Windows-compatible filesystem then this answer may be helpful: [*Windows-compatible filesystems' file time resolutions*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31521204/10765659).

Comment: it must be fat32 filesystem. there is a way to do this. someting in the mount command must change...